# Changing Report background on Print

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I've created a report that is based on black background (color fits with my application) - Of course when i attempt to print it - it turns out dark and well... wasteful (on ink/toner or whatever).

What i"m looking for is a way to view the report with a black background on the system but change the background to white when i print. I've looked around and that does not seem to be an inherent option of SSRS.

Is there some sort of workaround???

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround: Include a parameter in your report that has the options "Viewing only" and "Viewing for printing". Make your backgrounds and text colours conditional on the value of the parameter.